# Express not redirecting

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, redirect, post

Can't redirect from admin-login to admin-page, but on express cmd log it logs:

```
a1
a2
Correct
POST /admin-login 302 9.469 ms - 54
GET /admin-login? 304 5.112 ms - -
GET /admin-page 200 10.198 ms - 4428 
GET /stylesheets/admin-login-style.css 304 1.772 ms - -
GET /javascripts/admin-login.js 304 13.267 ms - -
```

which means that it entered conditional checking if username is a1 and password is a2, status code for adming-page is 200, but it's not redirecting, it only sends the data and stays on the admin-login page

```
<div class="container">
            <h1>Welcome</h1>

            <form class="form">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="username">
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password">
                <button type="submit" id="login-button">Login</button>
            </form>
        </div>

// frontend
fetch('http://localhost:8080/admin-login', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                username: username.value,
                password: password.value
            }),
        });
```

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const path = require('path');

router.get('/', (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public', 'admin_login', 'admin-login.html')));

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body.username);
    console.log(req.body.password);
    if (req.body.username === 'a1' && req.body.password === 'a2') {
        console.log('Correct');
        return res.redirect('http://localhost:8080/admin-page');
    } else {
        console.log('Not logged in');
        return res.redirect('back');
    }
});
// backend which gets the data
module.exports = router;
```

```
// admin panel page
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const path = require('path');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String
});

const User = mongoose.model('users', userSchema);

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public', 'admin_page', 'admin-page.html'));
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is redirecting, you're just not looking at the result.

A redirect is how you say, in HTTP: "What you want can be found at this URL instead".

The browser has asked for a URL using `fetch`. It was told that it could get the data from a different URL. It followed that automatically. It was given the response. The browser then gave that response back to your JavaScript. Where you do nothing with it.

You ignore the return value from `fetch` (which is a Promise that lets you look at the data).

A redirect doesn't mean "Navigate to a new page in the main browser window". You asked for data with `fetch` you have to deal with the response using `fetch`'s return value.

If you want to login and navigate to a new page, then **use a regular form submission**. Don't use Ajax.

Ajax is for when you make to make an HTTP request **without leaving the current page**.

Comment: So what should I change in this code in order it to work?

Comment: @AndrijaGajic — As I said, use a regular form submission instead of Ajax (and add a body-parser on the server that can handle the `enctype` you set for your form).

Answer (score -1):

Try sending the redirect with a status code 301

```
    res.sendStatus(301).sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public', 'admin_page', 'admin-page.html'));
```